# Android Studio populating ListView by unexpected data

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm working on a project now and it's my first for android.

I'm trying to populate a `ListView` from an SQLite database.
Problem is that the list gets populated with something related to the object and not the `name` or `id` for example that i want.
You can see what i mean in the log example below

`Player Count﹕ Player count: 48`

`Name is here:﹕ Name is here: Teris`

`Td is here:﹕ Td is here: packageName.player@435f3ea8`

**getAllPlayers** function from **DatabaseHelper.class**

```
public List<player> getAllPlayers() {
List<player> players = new ArrayList<player>();
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PLAYERS;

Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        player td = new player();
        td.setId(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))));
        td.setName((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME))));
        // adding to player list
        Log.e("Name is here: ","Name is here: " + td.getName());
        Log.e("Td is here: ","Td is here: " + td);
        players.add(td);
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
return players;
```

}

**PlayersActivity.class**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_players);

db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

player player1 = new player("Teris");
long player1_id = db.createPlayer(player1);

Log.e("Player Count", "Player count: " + db.getPlayersCount());

lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.playersList);

your_array_list = db.getAllPlayers();

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        your_array_list );

lv.setAdapter(adapter);
db.closeDB();
```

}

What am i doing wrong exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter<String>` tries to convert every `Player` object into a `String`. Default implementation returns something like "packageName.player@435f3ea8". 
Easy solution - override `toString` method inside your Player class:

```
   @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
```

That way every `Player` object will be represented as its name.

(btw looking at class name "player" hurts. It should start with uppercase :) )